# Autoselect free shipping option on checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-2.0.7, free-shipping

On checkout page, if free shipping available - this option should be already selected. How can I do this in Magento2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To auto select `free shipping` on checkout page, you can override a javascript from `Magento_Checkout` module. for this you have to create your module,

`Namespace/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

`Namespace/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

then create the `requirejs` to overriding the `checkout-data-resolver` js,

for this

`Namespace/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver': 'Namespace_Module/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
        }
    }
};
```

Now copy `checkout-data-resolver.js` from `Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model` in our module with the same path `Namespace_Module/view/frontend/web/js/model`

After that, change a condition inside the function `resolveShippingRates`

From:

```
............................

     if (ratesData.length == 1) {
                    //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);

                    return;
                }

.............................
```

To

```
.................................




     var selectedShippingRate = checkoutData . getSelectedShippingRate();
        var availableRate = false;
        if (selectedShippingRate == null) { // custom code start here
            for (var i = 0;i < ratesData . length;i++){
                if (ratesData[i] . method_code == 'freeshipping') {
                    selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[i]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            } else { // custom code end here
            if (ratesData . length == 1) {
                //set shipping rate if we have only one available shipping rate
                selectShippingMethodAction(ratesData[0]);
                return;
            }
        }

.....................................
```

Replace `Namespace/Module/` with your `YOUR_NAMESPACE` and `YOUR_MODULENAME`

1. Activate the module : `php bin/magento module:enable Namespace_Module`
2. Run a setup upgrade : `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
3. Do a static deploy : `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Thanks to [@Catalin Ionita](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/50200/catalin-ionita)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. But I did not create custom module , instead override checkout-data-resolver.js in my custom theme.

Comment: Good to know you made it , yes you can also use your custom theme Instead of module :) @Jeremy

Comment: It's works for me too. Thank you. Also I want to choose the cheapest auto set. How can I do that?